# Using a plus sign at the end of a bash function name

Tags: linux, bash, syntax

I need to create a bash function whose name ends with `+`. For example `foo+`. These work:

```
+foo() { true; }
foo+bar() { true; }
```

but this does not:

```
foo+() { true; }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

Why not? It doesn't complain about the `+`. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `+()` is an extglob (when enabled), so bash sees `someglob { true; }` which is not valid.

Here's it working without extglob:

```
$ shopt -u extglob
$ foo+() { echo bar; }
```

Here's it breaking with extglob:

```
$ shopt -s extglob 
$ foo+() { echo bar; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

Workarounds include adding a space before the `()` or using the `function` keyword:

```
foo+ () { echo bar; }
function foo+() { echo bar; }
```

Comment: Using `function` doesn't work when I'm the root user. Do you know why?

Comment: `function` is a bash extension and doesn't work if you use `sh` or `dash`